# Return array from Factory - AngluarJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, http

I'm looking to perform multiple `http.get` requests, save these values to an array and then return this array from my factory service.

My Service:

```
dashboardServices.factory('NexaService', ['$http', function($http, $scope, $route) {
    var factory = {};
   factory.getRoomDateRange = function() {
       var dataArray = [];
        dataArray.push($http.get(wsAddr+'urlOne'));
        dataArray.push($http.get(wsAddr+'urlTwo'));
        factory = dataArray;
        return factory;
   };
    return factory;
}]);
```

My Controller:

```
 $scope.getDateRangeRoom = function() {
    NexaService.getRoomDateRange()
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.records = data;
        conData = data;
        $scope.loaded = true;

       //logic

    .error(function (error) {
        $scope.loaded = true;
        $scope.error = true;
    });
  };
```

This is resulting in the error:

```
angular.js:11358 TypeError: NexaService.getRoomDateRange(...).success is not a function
```

If I only have a single request like below then the error is not reported:

```
factory.getRoomDateRange= function(){  
    factory = $http.get(wsAddr+'urlOne');     
    return factory;
};
```

My primary goal with this piece of code is to return the data from the multiple requests, if this can be performed without the array that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to inject the string dependencies in same order.

```
dashboardServices.factory('NexaService', ['$http', '$scope', '$route', function($http, $scope, $route)
```

Then modify the factory like this

```
dashboardServices.factory('NexaService', ['$http', '$scope', '$route', function($http, $scope, $route) {
    var factory = {};


    factory.getRoomDateRange = function() {
        var dataArray = [];
        dataArray.push($http.get(wsAddr + 'urlOne'));
        dataArray.push($http.get(wsAddr + 'urlTwo'));
        return dataArray;
    };
    return factory;
}]);
```

Since your servie return a array of `http` request use `$q.all` to send the multiple requsts one shot. remember to inject the `$q` also.

use `then` instead of `success` to catch the response. success is deprecated since angular version 1.4

```
$scope.getDateRangeRoom = function() {
    $q.all(NexaService.getRoomDateRange())
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response[0].data) // 1st request response 
            console.log(response[1].data) // 2nd request response 
            $scope.loaded = true; 

        }, function(error) {
            $scope.loaded = true;
            $scope.error = true;
        });
}
```

Comment: What format would this leave `conData` in? Previously it was JSON but it's coming up `undefined`

Comment: my mistake. check it again

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a promise that encapsulates all those promises:

```
factory.getRoomDateRange = function () {
  return $q.all([$http.get(wsAddr+'urlOne'), $http.get(wsAddr+'urlTwo')])
}
```

And then in your controller:

```
$scope.getDateRangeRoom = function() {
  NexaService.getRoomDateRange()
  .then(function (data) {
        $scope.records = data;
        conData = data;
        $scope.loaded = true;

       //logic
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      $scope.loaded = true;
      $scope.error = true;
  });
};
```

Comment: I'm getting `$q` is not defined?

Comment: @ColinShewell It is a service so you have to import it: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: How do you import third party services?

Comment: Thanks, I'm not getting - "angular.js:11358 TypeError: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined"

Comment: If you change `dashboardServices.factory('NexaService', ['$http', function($http, $scope, $route)` to `dashboardServices.factory('NexaService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q, $scope, $route)` it should be working.

Comment: That brings me back to - `TypeError: NexaService.getRoomDateRange(...).success is not a function`

Comment: You should call `.then` and `.catch` not `.success` and `.error`, read the docs for `$q` (especially the part under *The Promise API*): https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 0):

you can just return the promise:

```js
function getAll() {

  return $q.all(
    ['urlOne', 'urlTwo'].map(
      url => $http.get(wsAddr + url).then(r => r.data)
    )
  );
}

getAll()
  .then(list => console.log('list of values', list))
```